# Django deployement partial migrations issues?

Tags: django, git, web-deployment, database-migration, django-migrations

I was facing issues to efficiently replicate database changes on production. the best solution I can find is to gitignore migrations files so that I can isolate migration process on production. any better solutions to securely push model changes without deployment problems ?

Comment: The best way would be to take an exact copy of your production database on your dev machine (including the django_migrations table), then figure out what the problems are there when you rerun manage.py migrate.  You haven't given much detail of what the problems are.

Comment: problems may occur when making database structure changes that is not compatible with the current state of the database and needs manual data update to be compatible with new models.

Comment: That's when you use [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to automatically get your data in the right state.

Comment: How would that solve the problem ?

Comment: Your issue is that the data in your database is not compatible with the new schema, and that you need to update the data before you can run the migrations, right? A data migration allows you to programmaticaly change the data so that it is in a compatible state, without requiring any manual actions: you just run your migrations.

Comment: In general you will get these kinds of issues when the migrations on server and on your local machine are different. In this case you can stabilize your migrations(https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-create-initial-django-migrations-for-existing-schema/) at some point and change your git ignore file by allowing migrations that are stable.